# jQuery - watch for element height change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a element, which is absolute positioned and has a fixed height.

This element has a lot of child elements, which could change their contents, and in consequence their height.
The problem is that the container element doesn't auto expand to fit its children (because of it's fixed height and absolute position).

How can I can resize the main container to match its children height?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Optionally if you did want to/need to do it in jQuery something like the following would work:

html:

```
<div id='container'>
 <div class='child'>Content</div>
 <div class='child'>Content</div>
 <div class='child'>Content</div>
 <div class='child'>Content</div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.child{
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
}
#container{
    height: 120px;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

javascript:

```
var childHeight = 0
$('.child').each( function() {
    childHeight = childHeight + $(this).height();
})
$('#container').height(childHeight);
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/EcZZL/1/

Comment: that doesn't make any sense? you ARE using jQuery here! this is not pure javascript

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense, he asked how to do it in jQuery.

Comment: It does not answer the question. The question is how to watch for height change, not how to calculate height once.

Comment: Downvote all you like - the answer was accepted so I imagine it was in fact the answer they were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can change the css, this can be done fairly simply in css. Instead of setting `height` simply set `min-height` and your element should expand thusly.

[min-height](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_min-height.asp)

Comment: not working on IE.. any suggestion how to activate it on IE-7, would be great to use this